# Formatting Scrapy's output to XML

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

So I am attempting to export data scraped from a website using Scrapy to be in a particular format when I export it to XML.

Here is what I would like my XML to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <row>
    <field1><![CDATA[Data Here]]></field1>
    <field2><![CDATA[Data Here]]></field2>
  </row>
</data>
```

I am running my scrape by using the command:

```
$ scrapy crawl my_scrap -o items.xml -t xml
```

The current output I am getting is along the lines of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items><item><field1><value>Data Here</value></field1><field2><value>Data Here</value></field2></item>
```

As you can see it is adding the `<value>` fields and I am not able to rename the root nodes or item nodes. I know that I need to use [XmlItemExporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/exporters.html#xmlitemexporter), but I am not sure how to go about implementing this in my project.

I have tried to add it to the `pipelines.py` as it is shown [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters) but I always end up with with the error:

`AttributeError: 'CrawlerProcess' object has no attribute 'signals'`

Does any body know of examples of how to reformat the data when exporting it to XML using the `XmlItemExporter`?

**Edit:**

Showing my XmlItemExporter in my `piplines.py` module:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import XmlItemExporter

class XmlExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

**Edit (Showing modifications and Traceback):**

I modified the `spider_opened` function:

```
 def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file, 'data', 'row')
        self.exporter.start_exporting()
```

The trace back I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/root/self_opportunity/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
            current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
          File "/root/self_opportunity/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 265, in <lambda>
            spider=spider, reason=reason, spider_stats=self.crawler.stats.get_stats()))
          File "/root/self_opportunity/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scrapy/signalmanager.py", line 23, in send_catch_log_deferred
            return signal.send_catch_log_deferred(*a, **kw)
          File "/root/self_opportunity/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 53, in send_catch_log_deferred
            *arguments, **named)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/root/self_opportunity/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 134, in maybeDeferred
            result = f(*args, **kw)
          File "/root/self_opportunity/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/scrapy/xlib/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 47, in robustApply
            return receiver(*arguments, **named)
          File "/root/self_opportunity/self_opportunity/pipelines.py", line 28, in spider_closed
            self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        exceptions.AttributeError: 'XmlExportPipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter'
```

Comment: This error makes it sound like you are using a version of scrapy which is not 0.16. (Before 0.16, crawler did not have an attribute "signals".) Can you confirm your version?

Comment: @FrancisAvila Good catch. The ver. I was using was `0.13`. I have installed `0.16` now. I am now getting a `AttributeError: 'XmlExportPipeline' object has no attribute 'spider_opened'` error.

Comment: @FrancisAvila My code for my `pipelines.py` module has been added.

Comment: You have a typo: `spider_copened`. That's why you have an `AttributeError`.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Well now I feel stupid. I fixed the issue and now it runs correctly. My question is how can I get the ItemExporter to export the data in the way I want. I am looking for examples.

Comment: In my case the problem was in this part:
file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')

I was passing path_to_my_xml_output and this path wasn't created yet. I had to manually create all folders and re launch scraper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make `XmlItemExporter` do most of what you want simply by supplying the names of the nodes you want:

```
XmlItemExporter(file, 'data', 'row')
```

[See the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/exporters.html#xmlitemexporter).

The problem you have with `value` elements in your fields is because those fields are not scalar values. If XmlItemExporter encounters a scalar value, it simply outputs `<fieldname>data</fieldname>`, but if it encounters an iterable value, it will serialize like this: `<fieldname><value>data1</value><value>data2</value></fieldname>`.  The solution is to stop emitting non-scalar field values for your items.

If you aren't willing to do this, subclass `XmlItemExporter` and override its `_export_xml_field` method to do what you want when the item value is iterable. [This is the code for `XmlItemExporter`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/0.16/scrapy/contrib/exporter/__init__.py#L135) so you can see the implementation.

Comment: When I try to do the following `self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(file, 'data', 'row')` I get the exception:`exceptions.AttributeError: 'XmlExportPipeline' object has no attribute 'exporter'`. For some reason it doesn't like it when I add your modifications above.

Comment: Please show complete traceback and update your code to what you have. This error could not possibly be from *assignment*, it must be from *access* (and therefore not caused by this line).

Comment: Sorry for the delay in accepting this. overriding the `_export_xml_field` is one of the valid options you can use to export the `xml` in the format that you want. I ended up overriding the `serialize_field()` method as this was easier to comprehend.

Comment: @NicYoung Mind editing in your overridden serialize_field() method?