# How to indent XML properly in a scrapy spider

Tags: python, xml, scrapy

I am scraping a site and i want to generate an xml where each region is within the country it belongs to.

```
    def parse(self, response):

        #here i parse the country names

        country_names = response.xpath('//some countries/text()').extract()
        for name_of_country in countries :
            yield {"Country": name_of_country }
            yield Request(country_url, callback=self.parse_regions)

    def parse_regions(self, response):

        #here i parse the regions of each country

        regions= response.xpath('//some regions/text()').extract()
        for region in regions
            yield {"Region": region }
```

Now the XML appears like:

```html
<Country1></Country1>
<Country2></Country2> 
<Region>Region1</Region>
<Region>Region2</Region>
<Region>Region3</Region>
<Region>Region1</Region>
<Region>Region2</Region>
<Region>Region3</Region>
```

I want the XML to appear as follows:

```html
<Country1>
    <Region>Region1</Region>
    <Region>Region2</Region>
    <Region>Region3</Region>
</Country1>
<Country2>
    <Region>Region1</Region>
    <Region>Region2</Region>
    <Region>Region3</Region>
</Country2>
```

Comment: you can send `Country` to next requests using `meta=`in `Requests(..., meta={"Country": name_of_country })` and second request can use it to create one item with country and all regions inside, not many items with single regions.

Comment: can you add url to this page so we could test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never used `XML` but you can send `Country` to second request (using `meta=`) and then in `parse_region` create one element with all data.

I use http://quotes.toscrape.com to get some tags and use as `Country` and then I send to `parse_region` which get all regions and yield only one element.

Solution is not perfect because it gives

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
<item>
    <Country books>
        <value>“The person, ...”</value>
        <value>“Good friends, ...”</value>
    </Country books>
</item>
<item>
    <Country humor>
        <value>“The person, ...”</value>
        <value>“A day without ...”</value>
    </Country humor>
</item>
</items>
```

Maybe with own exporter you could change `<value>` into `<region>` and remove `<item>` - see [Formatting Scrapy's output to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962881/formatting-scrapys-output-to-xml)

Full working example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'myspider'

    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        for quote in response.css('.tag-item a'):
            country = 'Country ' + quote.css('::text').extract_first()

            url = quote.css('::attr(href)').extract_first()
            url = response.urljoin(url)

            #print('country/url:', country, url)

            # send `country` to `parse_region`
            yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'country': country}, callback=self.parse_region)

    def parse_region(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)

        country = response.meta['country']

        all_regions = response.css('.quote .text ::text').extract()

        #for region in all_regions:
        #    print('--- region ---')
        #    print(region)

        # create one `<countr>` with all <regions>`   
        yield {country: all_regions}


# --- it runs without project and saves in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',

    # save in XML, CSV or JSON
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'xml',     # 'json, csv
    'FEED_URI': 'output.xml', # 'output.json, output.csv
})
c.crawl(MySpider)
c.start()
```